# Select rows based on month by using a date column in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query to extract some data based on date as follows

```php
$duplicateCheckQuery = "SELECT * FROM vtag.supervisorupdate WHERE dateAdded=?";
$stmtDupQuery = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmtDupQuery, $duplicateCheckQuery)){
    echo "Details check in supervisor table SQL statement failed";
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtDupQuery,"s", $dateToCheck);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtDupQuery);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmtDupQuery);
    $totalOut = mysqli_fetch_array($result);          
}
```

This query is based on `date`.

But now I want to extract data based on month. But I don't have such a month column to extract data. The only available date information is this `dateAdded` column. I know there is a `MONTH` function in `MySql`. But I am not sure how to use it to filter data from this `dateAdded` column. Anyone know how to do it?

**Edit 1**
Sample of date in `dateAdded` column as below

[image]

Comment: Can you post example of data in `date` column?

Comment: Just added. Is that okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try MONTH function:

```
SELECT * FROM vtag.supervisorupdate WHERE MONTH(dateAdded) = 1
```

1 = January.

If your field is not date value, cast it to date:

```
 CAST(dateAdded AS DATE) as newDate;
```

OR
STR_TO_DATE(dateAdded, '%Y-%d-%m') as newDate

In the last:

```
SELECT * FROM vtag.supervisorupdate WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(dateAdded, '%Y-%d-%m')) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be

```
"SELECT * FROM vtag.supervisorupdate WHERE month(dateAdded) = ?"
```